# Which user fields in GitHub pushevent webhooks can be trusted?

Tags: git, github

Which fields in a GitHub v3 API "pushevent" webhook can be presumed to be authentic and not spoofed via git?

As discussed in length, git author fields can potentially be spoofed or even accidentally set incorrectly. I want to know which fields in this webhook actually *can* be truste

In the GitHub event example [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent), `baxterthehacker` and/or his email address are identified as causing the action in the following fields:

- commits[x].author/committer
- head_commit.author/committer
- pusher.name/email
- sender.login

I understand that the `author` field can be easily spoofed in git, so that field almost certainly can't be trusted. How about the `committer`, `pusher` and `sender` fields/subfields?